# Ignore value coming from channel

Tags: go, concurrency, channel, goroutine

I am writing a simple quiz game where is there are two timers, a global timer for the whole test and one for each question.

```
    timerGlobal := time.NewTimer(time.Duration(*timeLimit) * time.Second)

    correct := 0
problemLoop:
    for i, p := range problems {

        fmt.Printf("Problem #%d: %s = ", i+1, p.q)
        timerLocal := time.NewTimer(time.Duration(*timeQA) * time.Second)
        answerChan := make(chan string)
        go func() {
            var answer string
            fmt.Scanf("%s\n", &answer)
            answerChan <- answer
        }()
        select {
        case <-timerGlobal.C:
            fmt.Print("\nTimes up :(")
            timerLocal.Stop()
            break problemLoop
        case <-timerLocal.C:
            fmt.Println("\nTimes up for this question")
            timerLocal.Stop()
        case answer := <-answerChan:
            if answer == p.a {
                correct++
            }
            timerLocal.Stop()
        }

    }
    fmt.Printf("\nYou scored %d out of %d.\n", correct, len(problems))
```

Now the problem is, I tried Stop and Reset methods so that timer resets after answering or failing to answer every question, but if you fail once to answer within the time frame, the next question gets printed with msg ("\nTimes up for this question") every single time even though you have answered the question within the given time.

Comment: This approach is flawed. Once you call `fmt.Scanf()`, you can't "abort" it. So you can't time out a question if you're using `fmt.Scanf()`, because even if the timer expires, `fmt.Scanf()` won't know about it and will still wait for user input.

Comment: @icza I'm not sure that matters; the `Scanf` blocks and then writes to a channel, then the channel read is in the `select` with the timers, so aborting the `Scanf` isn't necessary. It will continue blocking and the next value that comes through will be treated as the answer for whatever the current question is when it's received.

Comment: @Adrian: I think that's what icza means by "this approach is flawed". :-) To the OP: consider having your user-input-reading goroutine deliver the user's input with a time stamp attached to it. Given a global clock, you can then order various events.

Comment: @Adrian No, what I mean is: if the user starts to type an answer, but the question times out, the loop proceeds to the next question, which launches another goroutine, calling `fmt.Scanf()`. Now there will be 2 concurrent `fmt.Scanf()` running, so the characters typed in the terminal will not be read by a single `fmt.Scanf()`, the answers read will not be the sequences of chars typed by the user. This concurrent reading is inherently flawed.